# Mixing some particles together - "Game physics for engineers"?

Tags: computational-physics, particle

I'd like to simulate how several particles mix together. For example, how do they settle when you throw them in a bucket? How do they assemble in zero-gravity? I might also want that they are "sticky" or that they can crack. I might also want to add some not-so-rigid things like drops of glue or snippets of strings.

The goal is not to have 100% accuracy in the physics, but more to end up with particle clusters that look similiar and have similiar geometric properties as their real-world counterparts.

I assume that this is a task which can get arbitrary difficult. Currently, I'm just looking for a **good starting point**:

- Terms and words to do a good internet research
- A good paper that can serve as a starting point
- A real good book, probably from game physics

Comment: Have you checked available game engines? For instance, Blender: https://www.blender.org/features/

Comment: The CUDA toolkit includes some examples of simulating particles. The code is pretty straight forward to understand and includes an openGL display for visualization.

Answer (score 4):

My experience has been in visual effects where simulation time is not as important as in games, but is still more important than in engineering.  The methods I'm familiar with are:

- The [material point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_point_method):  A continuum description of materials
- The [discrete element method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method):  A discrete description
- [Peridynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peridynamics): Nonlocal continuum description if fracture is important

For details on the Material Point Method in a visual effects context, see [Jiang's 2015 UCLA dissertation](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~dt/theses/jiang-thesis.pdf) titled "The Material Point Method for the Physics-Based Simulation of Solids and Fluids."  The references cited in that work will give you an idea of what the method has been used for.

For the Discrete Element Method, a good book is "[Understanding the Discrete Element Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111856720X)" (2014) by Matuttis and Chen (ISBN: 978-1-118-56720-3).

For Peridynamics there are two quite different approaches - bond-based and state-based.  You can read Gerstle's "Introduction to Practical Peridynamics" to get a feel for the method.  A test implementation of the bond-based method can be found on [my github](https://github.com/bbanerjee/ParSim/tree/master/Matiti/src).

All these methods can be expensive but remove the need for extensive user input to get the physics to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a challenging endeavor.

For deformable object, check out **level set methods**, e.g. this (old fashioned by still informative) website by [Sethian](https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Explanations/level_set_explain.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.fluidix.ca/

You'll find references for almost every example + some nice CUDA implementations.

I can't help with CFD, but for solids there's Discrete Element Method and Peridynamics. The key idea behind them is essentially the same.